# Survivors in Dishonored

Tags: dishonored

Is there any reason not to put Survivors asleep in Dishonored? Any sort of reward or motivation? Also, do they count against you for the Ghost trophy and/or having someone alerted to your presence?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends if a detection meter is shown above a Survivor's head upon them detecting your presence.

If you get a Survivor's detection meter up until it turns red, that will count as them detecting your presence, and will cause you not to get the ['Ghost' achievement](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Dishonored_Achievements). This may be a "motivation" to put Survivors asleep. This is the same for other NPCs, not just Survivors.

If a Survivor or any NPC is friendly to you or does not mind your presence, a detection meter won't appear and that will not count as 'detected'.

I noticed that on a high chaos playthrough, Survivors  will have a detection meter and might alert hostile, armed NPCs. While on a low chaos playthrough, they won't mind your presence (no detection meter).

Comment: So two things -- even hostile NPCs (like the Thugs holding Griff prisoner) don't count, for sure, as having been "detected" since no meter appears above them? Also, you can confirm that white bolts over an NPC's head don't count as having been "detected" in terms of achieving the "Ghost" achievement?

Comment: @JToland About your first question, I'd have to test that (I took them down stealthily in my two playthroughs) since they seem to be an exception - hostile, but no detection meter. But if they really don't have a meter, theoretically, I'd say they wouldn't count as 'detected'. About your second question, I'm pretty sure that won't count as 'detected', unless the bolts/meter turns red. This is based on experience and reports I've been reading from a few people. Those seem like a good question to ask here in Arqade though; it might get more attention if you make another question about it.

Answer (score 2):

no there are no penalties for killing or knocking out survivors but some of them like the ones found in the dunwall distillery can give you upgrades for helping the. like for example i once got a free pistol upgrade for helping a survivor. also you can gain bone charms and various other upgrades. so i would recommend not doing anything to the survivor because i can assure you they will definitely help you on your quest.